# Android Studio emulator doesn't starting my app

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a problem with my Android Studio Emulator. when I run my app, emulator started but doesn't start.

my app always shows this screen:

[image: Screen]

The console doesn't show any error: [image: error]

Comment: Check the logcat output and see if it tells you anything.  Have you tried started it via "Debug" so the debugger is automatically attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android emulator has a lot of weakness such as slow respond, bugs and others. Usually, when there is problem with emulator, I delete it and recreate new one. Try to change the specification of emulator such as CPU/ABI.

As alternative there is a recommendation of android emulator, try [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)